# How Bind for each id on database in Checkbox asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, data-binding, checkbox

I want to bind each id from database on SQL Server to a CheckBox. I bind database-data on ObjectContainerDataSource. And then I want to bind from Step 1 to the checkboxes. But it doesn't work. Here's my code:

**Table CancelInfo**

```
CancelId | CancelDetail
1 | Cancel01
2 | Cancel02
3 | Cancel03
```

**HTML FROM**

```
<asp:ObjectContainerDataSource ID="ocdCancel" runat="server"
                               OnSelecting="OcdCancel_OnSelecting"
                               DataObjectTypeName="DataAccessLayer.Master.CancelInfo"
                               UsingServerPaging="True" />
<div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" DataSourceID="ocdCancel">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkCancel01" DataSourceID="ocdCancel" value='<%# Eval("CancelId") %>'  />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

**Result Web Page ,,, □ >> CheckBox **

□ □ □ □ □ □

**But I want Result Web Page**

□ Cancel01

□ Cancel02

□ Cancel03

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperator template like so

```
<SeperatorTemplate><br /></SeperatorTemplate>
```

Then you have to bind ItemDataBound event before you call DataBind() on the repeater. In this event you look at the item count and display seperator when you can divide the item count by 5, like so:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Seperator)
  e.Item.Visible = ((e.Item.Parent as Repeater).Items.Count % 1 == 0);
```

Another solution is to add after asp:Checkbox the following:

```
<div style="clear: both" runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) % 1 == 0 %>"></div>
```